# Python write permission denied in docker container

Tags: docker, uwsgi, python-3.7

I'm trying to use pandas to write a csv to file in my flask app (wrapped with `uwsgi`) but I keep getting a `permission denied` error, despite adding uwsgi to my `user-group`, have I missed something?

### docker buildfile:

```
FROM kennethreitz/pipenv as build
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pipenv install --deploy --system \
 && pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt \
 && pipenv run python setup.py bdist_wheel

FROM ubuntu:bionic
COPY --from=build /app/dist/*.whl .
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN set -xe \
 && apt-get update -q \
 && apt-get install -y -q \
        python3-wheel \
        python3-pip \
        uwsgi-plugin-python3 \
 && python3 -m pip install *.whl \
 && apt-get remove -y python3-pip python3-wheel \
 && apt-get autoremove -y \
 && apt-get clean -y \
 && rm -f *.whl \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
 && mkdir -p /app \
 && useradd _uwsgi --no-create-home --user-group
USER _uwsgi
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/uwsgi", \
            "--master", \
            "--enable-threads", \
            "--die-on-term", \
            "--plugin", "python3"]
CMD ["--http-socket", "0.0.0.0:8000", \
     "--processes", "4", \
     "--chdir", "/app", \
     "--check-static", "static", \
     "--module", "server:app"]
```

Comment: Where does `/app` come from in the final image, and what are its permissions?  (I don't see anything that would cause a directory to be owned or writable by the `_uwsgi` user.)

Comment: Did you find a solution?